# Youtube link, iframe and css to make it appear like a pop up

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, popup

Could somebody please show me how I link the link I have created below, to the iframe below with CSS. I kinda want the iframe to be a pop up that almost fills the screen but cant seem to get my head around the CSS needed! I guess the iframe needs to be hidden first, but I really need help. Thanks guys for all your help

iframe

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

html

```
<a href="http://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0" target="_blank" class="play clearfix proximaBold relative"><span class="cta floatL">through the eyes of a bigsmile advert</span><span class="playIco floatL"></span></a>
```

Im trying to achieve the same as the video here http://adayinbigdata.com/ for my college assessment in rebranding.

Answer (score 1):

I used jquery for something very similar to this and it worked perfectly. Simply have a .onclick for a button or whatever you want the iframe to pop-up when its clicked, then fade in the iframe.

Have the iframe at the top of the DOM so you can position it relative to the view screen and a parent div to the iframe so you can grey out the page creating the illusion that the iframe is sitting on top of the page as a pop-up.

You'd simply put this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head. This connects to the jquery library. 
Then put this code anywhere into your document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#vid_button').click (function(){
    $('#pop-up').fadeIn(1000);
  });

}); 
</script>
```

The '#vid_button' is the button you want the video to pop-up on when clicked. And the '#vid' is the actual video you want to pop up. The number in the brackets next to the .fadeIn is the milliseconds it takes the iframe to appear. So it will take 1 second for this to complete.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42Kru/2/

Comment: I suppose, if you wanted pure css, you could have the iframe as the button, hide its content, have an :active selector on it. When clicked show the content and slowly expand the iframe to fill the window using a css animation.

Comment: $('#main').click (function(){
    $('<iframe width="420" height="345" src="<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').fadeIn(1000);

Comment: As I can't see you code, I can't verify whether or not that will work. However notice in my jsfiddle the iframe is sat within another div. The parent div (id of pop-up) has a width and height of 100% and is positioned absolutely as to not interfere with the rest of your site. It has a transulcent background for the pop up effect and should be hidden from the off with your css so that it can appear when the correct button is clicked.

Comment: When the button is clicked, the parent div should .fadeIn(1000) and the iframe should fade in with it. Position and size the iframe as you need. Simply play around with the jsfiddle to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: P.S. Its worth mentioning that the 'body' probably will have a padding by default. That's why the gray background might not cover the whole window. Simply put body{padding:0;} into your css. Also rgba(0,0,0,0.5) doesn't work in IE 9 or lower, you might have to use a translucent background image to get around this.

Comment: Hi Guys Im so sorry about this but I have done everything mentioned here and more but it will still not work, can somebody please visit www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile and give me their diagnosis as this is driving me insane, it works on mac and ios but not on any pc or laptop

Comment: It seems to be working for me. If you mean the first button saying "The average day of a big smile advert". When clicked the blured cycilist image expands then iframe fades in (Might be worth adding a simple 'x' button to close it again). Also I've tested it and the functionality has remained consistent up to IE8. Are you using an older browser?